# how can stop geting data from NSURL in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am getting data from nsurl but if i can change the view then stop receive NSData

I stop url receiveing data, below my code

```
-(void)AllPoint{

            NSString *passString=[NSString stringWithFormat:URL];
            //NSLog(@"all %@",passString);
            NSURL *url_album=[NSURL URLWithString:passString];

            dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
                NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url_album];
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(allPOINT:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
            });

        }
        -(void)allPOINT:(NSData *)responseData{

                if (responseData==nil){

                } else {

                    NSError* error;
                    NSMutableDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

                    //NSLog(@"all:%@",json);
                }
            }
```

how it possible?

Comment: You mean you don't want `allPOINT` to be called if you cancel? And the instance should not be retained if it is cancelled?

Comment: this method first call then go back then stop calling or receive responseData in -(void)allPOINT:(NSData *)responseData method. isthis possible?

Comment: what this mean 'kBgQueue'. its a main queue?

Answer (score 2):

blocks can't be canceled.. neither can the call `dataWithContentsOfURL` be canceled. It will finish no matter what.

you have two options

1. use NSURLConnection with the async variant that uses the delegate => then you can cancel the connection
2. just don't execute the callback allPOINT: if your View isn't visible anymore

... i;d go with way 2 as way 1 is a lot of extra work ;)

```
       __weak typeof(self) wself = self;
       dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
            typeof(wself) sself = wself;
            NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:sself->url_album];
            if(sself.visible)
                [sself performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(allPOINT:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
        });
```

a) notice I use a weak ref to self so as to not retain the self...

**b) you need a property `visible` which you control.** you set it to true in viewDidAppear and to false in viewWillDisappear

Comment: a third option would be to use AFNetworking or another wrapper for url connections

Comment: +1. I'd strongly suggest always using async URL loading.

Comment: if i call other nsurl in same view controller then this NSURL stop?